# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: wordpress, jet-engine

i was creating a CPT using JetEngine Plugins, when i build single post for the CPT i got this error message
[image: this error appear when i visit the singe post]

i've tried asking to senior developer on my department and Googling for the solution, but none was suitable for my case

Comment: Seems like a problem with the Elementor Pro plugin. Try reaching out to the Elementor support team and see if they can tell you more about this.